# Enabled browser javascript using code

Tags: browser

How do i enabled browser javascript using code?

using java,gwt or javascript

Comment: are you seriously asking how you can override user preferences to disable javascript.... using javascript?

Comment: Reminds me of that book by Joseph Heller...

Comment: Not a day goes by I don't thank the powers that be for making that impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Enabling javascript is a user preference and do not try to change that.

The best possible way will be to detect whether javascript is enabled or no and show the user a message indicating that script is turned off and they won't be able to access the full funcitonality of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The reason there is an option to turn off java and javascript it to *prevent* code from running client-side. You cannot use client-side code on a machine where client-side code has been disabled to enable client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

That's depends...

No as developer view, that is not possible otherwise that would be security breach on client-side and that's very uncool.

But yes as hackers view, for that you have to write your own bash or shell script depending on the environment and run it.